# is this a memory leak attaching to a view?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

is this a leak attach a closure to a textView?
countdownTextView is getViewById() and part of layout view.when

```
void postCountDownTimer(Long countDownTime, LinearLayout countdownContainer, TextView countdownTextView) {
    if (countDownTime >= System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        countdownTextView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                postCountDownTimer(countDownTime, countdownContainer, countdownTextView);
            }
        }, COUNTDOWN_DELAY_MILLIS);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Handler()` for this case since it will cause a memory leak based on what you're trying to do. `postDelayed` will push into a queue and when the context gets destroyed, the queue stays behind.

do something like:

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

void postCountDownTimer(Long countDownTime, LinearLayout countdownContainer, TextView countdownTextView) {
     if (countDownTime >= System.currentTimeMillis()) {
         mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                  mHandler.postDelayed(this, COUNTDOWN_DELAY_MILLIS);
             }
         }, COUNTDOWN_DELAY_MILLIS);
     }
}

//then on somewhere when your context gets destroyed, perform the call below:
mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is.  As long as countDownTime >= System.currentTimeMillis() is true, it will continuously post messages to a Handler on the UI thread.  This will keep a reference to countdownTextView and countdownContainer until that function is called and the condition evaluates false.  You really want to do it with your own Handler, so you can remove all messages in either onStop or onDestroy (preferably onStop so your UI isn't trying to update when backgrounded) and remove the references so it doesn't leak.